# Sails.js missing modules

Tags: node.js, npm, sails.js

Experiencing npm module troubles using sails.js.

The first problem was - the contents of assets/ was not being replicated to .tmp/public as documentation indicates.  There have been other errors as well.

Research has shown - there are missing modules, one of which is grunt.  Doing a

```
npm install grunt
```

does make the .tmp/public start working.

But there have been other errors when trying to use the framework.

Install Details:

Server instance: Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
(recently deployed, no other changes to server except for node and sails.js)

```
node --version
v0.12.4
```

(built from sources)

```
npm -v
2.10.1

sails --version
0.11.0
```

sails installed using:
    sudo npm install sails -g

Create a new application:
    sails new testproject

```
cd testproject
npm list
```

produces a long list of missing npm modules to stderr:

```
npm ERR! missing: colors@~0.6.2, required by grunt@0.4.2
npm ERR! missing: grunt@~0.4.0, required by grunt-contrib-clean@0.5.0
npm ERR! missing: lodash@~2.4.1, required by grunt-contrib-coffee@0.10.1
npm ERR! missing: grunt@~0.4.0, required by grunt-contrib-coffee@0.10.1
npm ERR! missing: grunt@~0.4.0, required by grunt-contrib-concat@0.3.0
npm ERR! missing: grunt@~0.4.0, required by grunt-contrib-copy@0.5.0
```

and several others.

This seems inexplicable - how could this (missing npm modules) be overlooked?  I am new to node - and could have missed something.

Reviewing the getting started page, I didn't notice anything obvious.

This framework seems well-designed - uses some great npm modules.

Has anybody experienced these and found what is needed to fix?

Comment: You are not the only one. I got this too. . If you look at the package.json file of sailsproject , grunt@0.4.2 is one of the dependencies that sailsproject  has.Inside  sailsproject/node_modules/grunt,   you will find that the package.json file of grunt has color@0.6.2 as dependencies but sailsproject/node_modules/grunt/node_modules does not have color. To resolve this, you just do a npm install inside grunt.     However, I always see  errors like that in other projects, so do not think this is specially harmful.   I think it is almost impossible to resolve all nested dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the missing: colors@~0.6.2, required by grunt@0.4.2   , just navigate to the node_modules/grunt, do a npm install to install the missing dependencies.